How to share Google Dataplex/Data Catalog metadata outside the organization
We are sharing some BQ datasets with a third party (outside our org) using analytics hub. So, the subscriber is able to create a linked dataset in their project and any queries they run are billed to their project.
Now, we are exploring enriching the metadata for some of these datasets that are being shared using Dataplex. Are there any use cases/best practices on how this metadata can be shared? Two options come to mind:

Option1: Enrich the metadata in Dataplex/Data Catalog and push it to a BQ dataset. And then share the same using Analytics Hub. This would be the cleanest solution. But I am not clear on the following points:

Is it possible to push Dataplex/Data Catalog metadata to BQ?
It seems possible to create two types of metadata for a BQ table in Dataplex, the Dataplex entity and the Data Catalog entry. Can both/either/none be pushed?
Link about question related to Dataplex vs. Data Catalog metadata: Link


Option2: Give a user from the 3rd party permissions to view the metadata in Dataplex. Nor sure if this possible, to have someone outside the org. have access to only the metadata for certain datasets in dataplex. Maybe organize data in lakes and then grant access at the lake level, but in that case, would not be able to share the Data Catalog metadata. This would however not be the preferred approach, to have a 3rd party user access resources directly inside the project.


Detailed discussion here in the google cloud community forum: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/How-to-share-Google-Dataplex-Data-Catalog-metadata-outside-the/m-p/749400#M5947
